# Is it possible to add a list to an irregular column?

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to programmatically generate a PDF file.

I am using an irregular column (a `ColumnText`in text mode) and am having difficulty adding an unordered list to the column.

The `ColumnText` class's `AddText` method only accepts a `Phrase` or `Chunk`, so I can't add a `List` directly. I have tried adding a `List` to a `Paragraph` and then adding the `Paragraph` to the `ColumnText` but the result is the list items appear concatenated one after another and not as a bulleted list.

Can this be done or do I need to explore an alternative route?

**ANSWER:** There is no support in iText to add lists to irregular columns. However, it is possible to render lists in irregular columns with a bit of legwork. I blogged about it here: [Rendering Lists in Irregular Columns Using iText / iTextSharp](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2013/10/16/rendering-lists-in-irregular-columns-using-itext-itextsharp.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `AddText()`, you're using `ColumnText` in **text mode**. If you want to use a `List`, you should use `ColumnText` in **composite mode**. You can switch from text mode to composite mode by replacing `AddText()` by `AddElement()`.

Comment: I am using irregular columns, though, and therefore cannot use composite mode (at least to my knowledge). Are there any workarounds or are using lists in an irregular column an impossibility?

Comment: Using lists in an irregular column isn't supported.

Comment: That's what I figured - thanks for the confirmation.